# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, oracle, amazon-ec2, odp.net

After deploying asp.net app to the server im getting this error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Im using Amazon EC2 instance webserver Windows-2008R2-SP1, i downloaded and installed Oracle client from this link 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html lateset one Release3

i checked Oracle.DataAcees version in webserver Windows/assembly folder it is same as `Version=2.112.2.0, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342` which is in config file.

Please let me know how to solve this issue. Your help is very much needed.

Thankyou

Comment: Looks like you need an oracle .dll put into your /bin

Comment: project has the oracle.dataaccess.dll in bin folder.. any ideas pls

Comment: Use `fuslogvw` (fusion log viewer) to see where it's trying to load the assemblies and their dependencies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the webserver goto **IIS console** select **applicationpool** that you are using and 
**right click->Advanced settings->Enable 32 bit=true**

Solved issue. Hope someone will benefit ....